# In RIDE IDE, getting error while running my first test case - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

Tags: python, robotframework

In the env variables, Python27 and Python27\Scripts are set. Chromedriver is present under Scripts folder. Also the Python version is 2.7.9, robot version is 3.0.2 (running on Python 2.7.9 on win32). SeleniumLibrary has been added in the Directory and on the Test Suite folders The test case is about launching Chrome browser and navigating to a URL. However the test fails with the error - TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'. Please help.

Testcase:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ../Lib/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/

*** Variables ***
${url}            https://<URL>
${browser}        chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Logon
    Open Browser    ${url}    ${browser}
```

**Error Details.**
Starting test: 
20230309 19:38:36.731 :  INFO : Opening browser 'chrome' to base url '.
20230309 19:38:36.732 :  INFO : Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.
20230309 19:38:36.736 :  FAIL : TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
Ending test:

Comment: Where's the code that generated the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this is not the correct way to import SeleniumLibrary.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ../Lib/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/
```

If it was really correctly installed (probably forcing to an old version, see [Release Notes 4.5.0](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/SeleniumLibrary-4.5.0.rst)), for example like:

```
pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.5.0
```

And this implies you must upgrade Robot Framework to 3.1.2.

Then the correct way to use is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
```

You will have to find the correct versions of Browsers and their Webdrivers.

You will have a hard time to still continuing using Python 2.7. It is strongly recommended to use Python 3 (I recommend to stay at most on Python 3.10, for now).

Comment: Hello, Now I use Python version 3.7.5, Robot Framework is 3.1.2. In Pycharm, packages like RobotFramework, Selenium, RobotFramework-SeleniumLibrary packages are added to Pycharm, Intellibot plugin also added to the Pycharm. The chrome browser version is 112.0.5615.121, the best matching ChromeDriver downloaded is 112.0.5615.49 and this .exe was kept in Scripts folder under Python37 folder and the same path is provided in Env variables Path. Now i can see that browser is lauched, but URL is not navigated to. In the URL bar, it shows "data:," and stays there indefinitely.

Comment: Continuation - If I close the browser at above state, i get below error in terminal - 
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: Three things. First the initial question is answered, and you may accept it as valid. Second, you should edit the question title to remove RIDE, because it is not related. Finally, you should consider if your URL contains some error or problem. Experiment with a known valid URL, for example: https://robotframework.org/